# how to call my second entity with property?

Tags: php, symfony

I've actually a problem with `SonataAdminBundle`.

I have a file **admin.yml**:

```
sonata.admin.Produit:
    class: Kayser\PlatformBundle\Admin\ProductionAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Produits", label: "Les Pains & Viennoiseries" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Kayser\PlatformBundle\Entity\Product
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [KayserPlatformBundle]]

sonata.admin.Produit:
    class: Kayser\PlatformBundle\Admin\ProductionAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Produits", label: "Les Pains & Viennoiseries" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Kayser\PlatformBundle\Entity\ProductImage
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [KayserPlatformBundle]]`
```

and my **productionAdmin.php**:

```
class ProductionAdmin extends Admin
{
// Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('description', 'text', array('label' => 'Description'))
        ->add('name')
        ->add('url', 'entity', array(
        'class'    => 'KayserPlatformBundle:ProductImage',
        'property' => 'name',
        'multiple' => true))
    ;
}

// Fields to be shown on filter forms
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('url', 'entity', array(
        'class'    => 'KayserPlatformBundle:ProductImage',
        'property' => 'name',
        'multiple' => true))
    ;
}

// Fields to be shown on lists
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('name')
        ->add('description')
                    ->add('url', 'entity', array(
        'class'    => 'KayserPlatformBundle:ProductImage',
        'property' => 'name',
        'multiple' => true))
    ;
}
}
```

and 2 entity `Product.php` and `ProductImage.php` (they have no problem).

So  how to call my second entity with property ? :)

Comment: Your question is unclear, which second entity, and where to call it? What do you try to achieve

Comment: I try to call "$url" from ProductImage.php (my second entity). I call this entity in my admin.yml file at the end of this file.

Answer (score 0):

To get a property of another entity in your admin file, I use something like this:

```
->add(
    'productImage',
    'entity',
     array(
       'label' => 'Url',
       'class' => 'path/to/ProductImage',
       'property' => 'url',  
     )
  )
```

This is what the docs give for example:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class PostAdmin extends Admin
{
   // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
   protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
   {
       $formMapper
           ->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'Post Title'))
           ->add('author', 'entity', array('class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User'))
           ->add('body') //if no type is specified, SonataAdminBundle tries to guess it
       ;
   }
```

More info in the [docs](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/architecture.html)